# Correcting path separator with Regex or Other Methods

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to check to see if a path has more than two \'s and replace them with two \'s.

For example if the path I have looks like:

```
C:\\documents\\\\temporary
```

replace the `\\\\` with `\\` so the result would be:

```
C:\\documents\\temporary
```

At the moment what I am using in C# (which doesn't work) is this:

```
strVersion = Regex.Replace(strVersion, @"\\\\{4}", "\\\\");
```

Edit: This is fixed now I used Daniel Gimenez's solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the regex `\\{2,}` to replace instaces of 2 or more slashes.  `{n,}` means the pattern can occur any number of times from `n` to infinity.

```
strVersion = Regex.Replace(strVersion, @"\\{2,}", "\\");
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/nj5o7di7)

Now I'm not sure if you just want one slash back or two.  If you want two back change it to:

```
strVersion = Regex.Replace(strVersion, @"\\{2,}", @"\\");
```

Comment: Yes! It worked :) Thank you. I always get mixed up with the Regex editors online since you can't actually debug it in C#...

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer is correct, but to add to it:

If you are not expecting escaped strings, it would make sense to also replace single instances of backslashes with two.

```
strVersion = Regex.Replace(strVersion, @"\\+", @"\\");
```

Answer (score -1):

In your initial code, my guess would be that

```
strVersion = Regex.Replace(strVersion, @"\\{4}", "\\");
```

Replaces with '\' rather than "\\".  Perhaps try @"\\" or "\\\\"? (It's a bit annoying that the stackoverflow text editor actually treats the \ like a string would, so in my solution I actually had to type out 4 \'s for the first and 8 for the second)

Comment: The problem is with `{4}` not the number of `\`'s, see Daniel's answer.